# importing contacts from gmail using contacts gem and doing authentication at email client site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, contacts

Currently I am asking user to fill email and password in a form for a specific email client say Gmail. I think the authentication should be done at the email client. That would be convincing.

How to redirect authentication to email clients.

So that, user types the details in gmail and gmail returns a token to my web server, so that user can retrieve her contacts in my web app.

Is there any support to do this using contacts gem? Any other gems to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have that feature working using the [omnicontacts gem](https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts)

```
gem 'omnicontacts'
```

I basically followed the instructions to set it up, you need to specify (in a `initializer`) the importer, and then the needed data, like

```
Rails.application.middleware.use OmniContacts::Builder do
  importer :gmail, GMAIL_CONFIG['client_id'], GMAIL_CONFIG['client_secret']
end
```

and then I have something like this in `routes.rb`:

```
 match '/contacts/:importer/callback' => 'mailer_contacts#callback'
```

Lastly you setup your `MailerContactsController` with the `callback` action (for example redirecting where you need it to go).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Will accept it after getting it done.

Comment: Rails server fails to start  in rails 2. 
        `Rails.application.middleware.use OmniContacts::Builder`  //fails 
 Does omnicontacts support Rails 2?

Comment: I don't know for sure what the problem is because I don't have the error, but even if the gem doesn't say if it supports Rails 2, you'll have to take a look at how to add middleware to a Rails 2 app ( like this: http://goo.gl/QdC7k )